# Flutter: How to synchronize synchron static method with asynchron non-static method?

Tags: flutter, dart

When I start the app, it should check if it is possible to use biometric authentication (fingerprint/face id). I have a class that checks this and the login page need the result of it. I have the following code:

```dart
class LocalAuthenticationUtil with ChangeNotifier {
  static LocalAuthentication _auth = LocalAuthentication();
  static List<BiometricType> biometricTypes;
  static bool haveBiometrics = true;
  bool _biometricAuthenticated = true;

  static LocalAuthenticationUtil _instance;

  static LocalAuthenticationUtil getInstance() {
    if (_instance == null) {
      _instance = LocalAuthenticationUtil();
      print("GetInstance CanCheckBiometrics before");
      _instance._canCheckBiometrics();
      print("GetInstance CanCheckBiometrics after");
      if (haveBiometrics) {
        _instance.addListener(() {
          _instance.authenticate();
        });
        _instance.authenticate();
      }
    }

    return _instance;
  }

  Future<void> _canCheckBiometrics() async {
    print("CanCheckBiometrics before");
    haveBiometrics = await _auth.canCheckBiometrics;
    print("CanCheckBiometrics after");
    if (haveBiometrics) {
      biometricTypes = await _auth.getAvailableBiometrics();
    }
  }

  set biometricAuthenticated(bool value) {
    if (_biometricAuthenticated != value) {
      _biometricAuthenticated = value;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
```

When the code runs this is the result:

```
I/flutter (23495): GetInstance CanCheckBiometrics before
I/flutter (23495): CanCheckBiometrics before
I/flutter (23495): GetInstance CanCheckBiometrics after
I/flutter (23495): CanCheckBiometrics after
```

While the order that I want to happen is:

```
I/flutter (23495): GetInstance CanCheckBiometrics before
I/flutter (23495): CanCheckBiometrics before
I/flutter (23495): CanCheckBiometrics after
I/flutter (23495): GetInstance CanCheckBiometrics after
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not `await`ing `_instance._canCheckBiometrics();`

Dart executes synchonously until it hits an `await`, at which point the function immediately returns, but "remembers where it was", so it can continue where it left off when the `await`ed `Future` completes:

Here, when you call `_instance._canCheckBiometrics()`, it immediately runs the first `print` statement, then hits the `await _auth.canCheckBiometrics` and immediately returns a `Future` representing the result of `_instance._canCheckBiometrics()`.

Simply replace `_instance._canCheckBiometrics()` with `await _instance._canCheckBiometrics()` and it should work.

BTW, you can create an `analysis_options.yaml` file to customise your linter warnings for your project. One in particular, called `unawaited_futures` warns you when you have a `Future`-returning function in an async context that doesn't have an `await`. This is usually an error, but you can suppress it manually if you're certain. This rule often helps catch bugs like this.
To use the linter, check out: https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options#enabling-linter-rules

Comment: "await _instance._canCheckBiometrics()" - I can't since the getInstance() method is not async. If I make it async, I have to change everywhere else where I use the getInstance() method to expect a future instead just object itself what can lead to other things that not initialized when wanna use it...

Answer (score 0):

cameron1024 is right.
What you need to do is to create a StatefulWidget which will redirect the user once the check is completed.

```dart
class AuthWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  AuthWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AuthWidgetState createState() => _AuthWidgetState();
}

class _AuthWidgetState extends State<AuthWidget> {
  @override
  void initState() { 
    super.initState();
    checkBiometrics(); // perform the check asynchronously and then use Navigator.of(context).push/replace
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Display a loader while checking
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  }
}
```